# Sys.Application.add_load Problem with Modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the current problem, let's explain the context before :

I have a Modal popup extender who contains a form. There is a feature "Save and Add New", when the user click on this button the data in the form is saved in the database during postback and the page is reloaded.

I want this Modal popup to appear again on the page_load allowing the user to enter new data without clicking again on the button who show this Modal Popup.

I've tried to call it this way first :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ModalPopup", "ShowModalPopup(""" & Me.formModalButton.ID & """);", True)
```

but the problem was when the function was called my Modal Popup was not existing yet on the page. Because of that the code was crashing on the

```
var modal = $find('myModal');
```

So, I found that other way and it's working **almost** perfectly.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ModalPopup", "Sys.Application.add_load(function() {ShowModalPopup(""" & Me.formModalButton.ID & """)};", True)
```

The modal is showing up on the page load like I want, but the problem is if I click on any other button on my page the Modal Popup is also appearing again.

Example : I have another Modal Popup for deleting data, when I click on the button, both Modal are appearing, which is not cool.

Does anyone have a clue about how to fix that or a better way to do it ?

P.S. I'm not calling to Modal popup server-side because the javascript function exist in the page, so I don't want to create a copy of this function in the RegisterStartupScript.

Thx for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround for my current problem.

I'm still using the ClientScript.Resgister[...] but this time I also change the OnClientClick Javascript function of my cancel button.

So when the guy select the feature "Save and Add New", when the page reload and the modal Show again if he click on Cancel I do a postback to the server just to reload the page and solve those weird behavior.

I also think, the problem could exist because of the different Update Panel in my code, but I need them to make the Modal Popup Extender working.

Anyway, I discovert that's it's not even working in Opera and Safari, but the Whole thing (Ajax Control toolkit - Modal popup extender).

It's a chance the compagny here don't care about the other and support officially only IE. In my case, I wanna make it works at least in FF and Chrome too.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ModalPopup", "Sys.Application.add_load(function() {ShowAddModalPopup(""" & Me.imgAdd.ID & """)});", True)
                btnCancel.OnClientClick = "resetDefaultValue();__doPostBack('" & btnCancel.ID & "','onclick')"
```

So there is the code, also in FF another error appear,

**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0**

And I found this workarounf for it, it's not the best but I lost enought time with this...

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "WorkAroundFF", "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest); function endRequest(sender, args) { /* Check to see if there's an error on this request.*/ if (args.get_error() != undefined) { $get('Error').style.visibility = ""visible""; /* Let the framework know that the error is handled, so it doesn't throw the JavaScript*/ alert. args.set_errorHandled(true); } }", True)
```

So thx for your help Ramesh, i'm pretty sure your solution would work if it was not my Update Panels.

Hope that could help someone else.

Comment: Actually, I also think that the fact I'm still on VS2005 on framework 2.0 may cause more troubles. Our Ajax Control Toolkit is not on the last version, so 
I think I'll disable the feature for the moment and test it later on VS2008 because I've got other kind of bugs and I'm sure it's on their side.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code snippet

```
//Declares gloabal variable
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),"vardeclaration","var reloadModal;",true);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ModalPopup", "Sys.Application.add_load(

function() 
{
   reloadModal = function() {ShowAddModalPopup(""" & Me.imgAdd.ID & """);};
   Sys.Application.add_init(reloadModal);
}
);", True)
```

This would allow you to use

```
function cancelClick()
{
   Sys.application.remove_init(reloadModal);
}
```

Comment: Hello, first thx for the reply.

Unfortunatly, if I use the Sys.Application.add_init instead of the add_load I have the same problem than before, my modal popup extender does not exist when the function is called, so I got a null reference exception on the $find('myModal').

Comment: @ForceMagic : I am sorry, I misread it. Can't you Register this script only on specific button click on server side?

Comment: Yes I can do that but the problem remains there once the script is registered. Maybe I should try to Unload on the Cancel button. With Sys.application.remove_load

Actually, when the user click on cancel, the script stay there so the Modal is popin up again when a click occurs on the page.

Comment: Can you remove the script at client side before you do a postback?

Comment: I think I can, I'll try it ! actually I changed a bit the way I'm calling the function and your suggestion for the add_init is working !!! so I'll try to remove from load on the Cancel Button! I'll post back my solution if it's working ! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm still stuck on "removing" the stored function after the first call. I mean, when he show me the Modal popup again on the page_load, if I click on cancel, the script stay there and on any other click it appear again. Do you want me to post my code in an awnser to see if you could help ? thx

Comment: Hello ! I have a bad news and a good news :P

The good news your code is working well! I learned  how to declare a global function.

The bad news, even if I call remove_init(reloadModal), the behavior is still there when I click on another button both. Maybe it's not the good way to do what I need ?

Comment: Yes also. I am confused now. If things happen Async, it should not close the modal browser on click of a submit button.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty confuse me too seriously. I think I understand, that After the Sys.Application.add_init, because I have other JavaScript auto generated code in the same page, there is a Bug with the ScriptManager. I think, he is calling each time the Modal Popup after I register it Client Side.

Comment: It's the only thing I could imagine. Maybe, my custom javascript is doing some "interference" with the current javascript generated by the ScriptManager. Actually, even on the Forums.Asp.Net, I've seen nobody using the Modal popup as much as me and so much customized than me. I'm clueless really :(